# Pattern matching of instance implementation

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, typeclass

I'm trying to implement show method of a data type.

```
data OptionList a b = EmptyOpt | OptionList { optListHead :: a, optListTail :: b } deriving (Read)

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (OptionList a b) where
    show (OptionList a EmptyOpt) = "{" ++ (show a) ++"}"
    show (OptionList EmptyOpt b) = "{" ++ (show b) ++"}"
    show (OptionList a b) = "{"++ (show a) ++ ", " ++ (show b) ++"}"
    show EmptyOpt = ""
```

I want the OptionList not to show a comma if one of `a` or `b` has a value constructed by EmptyOpt. But the compiler shows the following error:

```
OptionList.hs:11:28:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘b’
                with actual type ‘OptionList t0 t1’
      ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at OptionList.hs:10:10
    Relevant bindings include
      show :: OptionList a b -> String (bound at OptionList.hs:11:9)
    In the pattern: EmptyOpt
    In the pattern: OptionList a EmptyOpt
    In an equation for ‘show’:
        show (OptionList a EmptyOpt) = "{" ++ (show a) ++ "}"

OptionList.hs:12:26:
    Couldn't match expected type ‘a’
                with actual type ‘OptionList t2 t3’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
          the instance declaration at OptionList.hs:10:10
    Relevant bindings include
      show :: OptionList a b -> String (bound at OptionList.hs:11:9)
    In the pattern: EmptyOpt
    In the pattern: OptionList EmptyOpt b
    In an equation for ‘show’:
        show (OptionList EmptyOpt b) = "{" ++ (show b) ++ "}"
```

*UPDATE*: OptionList is supposed to be something like a typeless list.

```
(+:) :: a -> b -> (OptionList a b)
infixr 5 +:
t1 +: t2 = OptionList t1 t2
```

So, a list like: `0 +: "test" +: True` would be defined like `OptionList Int (OptionList String (OptionList Bool EmptyOpt))` And would be `show`n as `{0, {"test", {True}}}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*An update for your update.* You can make it work if you are willing to turn on some extensions:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

data EmptyOpt = EmptyOpt

data OptionList a b =
  OptionList a b
  deriving (Read)

instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (OptionList a b) where
  show (OptionList a b) = "{ " ++ show a ++ ", " ++ show b ++ " }"

instance {-# OVERLAPPING  #-} (Show a) => Show (OptionList a EmptyOpt) where
  show (OptionList a EmptyOpt) = "{ " ++ show a ++ " }"

(+:) :: a -> b -> (OptionList a b)
infixr 5 +:
t1 +: t2 = OptionList t1 t2

test = 0 +: "test" +: True +: EmptyOpt
```

But personally I would try to make do with something like

```
data Option = B Bool | I Int | S String
data OptionsList = Empty | OptionsList Option OptionsList
```

---

Your trouble is that the instance head (`(Show a, Show b) => Show (OptionList a b)`) says that you are implementing `Show` for `OptionList a b` where `a` and `b` are any types with `Show` instances, but in your implementation you require that both `a` and `b` actually are of type `OptionList`.

Perhaps you would change your type to be more like an ordinary list:

```
data OptionList a
  = EmptyOpt
  | OptionList { optListHead :: a
              ,  optListTail :: OptionList a}
  deriving (Read)
```

Then you can have an instance:

```
instance (Show a) => Show (OptionList a) where
  show (OptionList a EmptyOpt) = "{" ++ show a ++"}"
  show (OptionList a b) = "{"++ show a ++ ", " ++ show b ++"}"
  show EmptyOpt = ""
```

Comment: Hah, I had exactly the same idea :)

Comment: I don't want that the elements have all the same type.

Comment: @BrunoCorrêaZimmermann: That's more or less impossible with Haskell: Haskell is statically typed. You could define a list of `Either a b` types such that each element is either type `a` or `b`. But in Haskell you know in advance the type of elements. If you want this flexibility, you should use a dynamically typed language like Python.

Comment: @BrunoCorrêaZimmermann: that is very tricky. Perhaps you can make do with a type `data Option = B Bool | I Int | S String` and `data OptionsList = Empty | OptionsList Option OptionsList`? If that doesn't suffice you would have to look into something called heterogenous lists, which are possible to use in Haskell but very nice. I would try to find another solution for your use case.

Comment: But I was able to indeed create a list like that with this data. The problem is just in its stringizing. I can make a list to be stringized as `{0, {"test", {True, }}}`. What I want is `{0, {"test", {True}}}`. The problem is the additional comma, because a value created with EmptyOpt is stringified as ``.

Comment: I know that Haskell is statically typed, but this is the fun. Creating tricks.

Comment: The problem is not only in creating lists with this type, but also in consuming them. They are pretty easy to create (eg by adding a special type-level Nil to indicate the end of a list), but you end up with awkward types like `DynList Int (DynList String (DynList Bool Nil))`, which means that you must know at compile time the length of the list and the types of all its elements: it might as well just be a single data constructor at that point, since it doesn't have the runtime flexibility a list does.

Comment: See the update, perhaps that would work for you? But this suffers from the problems @amalloy mentions.

Comment: My idea was to build a list for any type. But I think I'll give up and do something like: `Option = OptInt Int | OptStr String | OptBool Bool`

Comment: I would hardly call `FlexibleInstances` instances frightening. It is one of the most benign extensions - I usually wish it was enabled by default.

Comment: @Alec you're right. But `OverlappingInstances` are slightly scarier I believe.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in your instance declaration:

```
instance (Show a, Show b) => Show (OptionList a b) where
    show (OptionList a EmptyOpt) = "{" ++ (show a) ++"}"
    show (OptionList EmptyOpt b) = "{" ++ (show b) ++"}"
    show (OptionList a b) = "{"++ (show a) ++ ", " ++ (show b) ++"}"
    show EmptyOpt = ""
```

You **use dataconstructors**. Therefore Haskell derives - correctly - that you actually define a `show` over `OptionList (OptionList c d) (OptionList e f)`: after all `EmptyOpt` is a construct of `OptionList a b`, so **you cannot use these as arguments** since in the head of your instance you say you are going to define the instance for `OptionList a b` with generic `a` and `b`.

So it is not clear for me what you aim to do; modifying it to:

```
instance (Show a, Show b, Show c, Show d) => Show (OptionList (OptionList a b) (OptionList c d)) where
```

would not help either, since the structure is recursive, and you thus would define the instance with infinite recursive depth.

The only thing that seems reasonable to me, is that your data definition is wrong, and should be something like:

```
data OptionList a = EmptyOpt | OptionList { optListHead :: a, optListTail :: OptionList a }
```

in which case, you can define it as:

```
instance Show a => Show (OptionList a) where
    show (OptionList a b) = "{"++ show a ++ ", " ++ show b ++"}"
    show EmptyOpt = ""
```

or something along these lines.

Answer (score 0):

My idea was to create a type independent list. And this list's elements were supposed to hold any type declared. But I will give up and do something like a C Union:

```
data Option = OptStr String | OptInt Int | OptBool Bool
```